# Why does Bash show me the whole path of my symlinked script when I tab complete its name?

Tags: linux, bash, ln

I'm trying to do my own command (`test.sh` script).

The script works perfect and I created a soft link (i.e., `ln -s /home/test.sh ~/bin/test`).

And when I call from anywhere inside RHEL, it also works perfectly.

***But my problem is the next one:***

When from the command line I'm writing the name of the command (`test`), and I press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, the system shows me the full path and name of my script, i.e., `$ /home/bin/test`, and I want that it only shows me the name of the command (`$ test`).

Is that possible? How can I do it?

Comment: Maybe you have the readline "expand tilde" option enabled – you can check with `bind -V | grep 'expand-tilde'`. If it is set to `on`, you can add `set expand-tilde off` to your `~/.inputrc`; to check if it worked, start a new login shell or reload the configuration (typically with Ctrl-X-R), make sure the `bind` command from above shows now `off`, then try tab completion.

Comment: sorry, but I tried "bind" and on RHEL is saying me "bind: not found".

Comment: What's the output of `type bind`?

Comment: $ bind

$ -ksh: bind: not found [No such file or directory]

Comment: your cmd shell is `ksh`, not `bash`. Can you switch to `bash`? I don't think `ksh` has a`bind` cmd. Good luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you need is an alias. In RHEL/CENTOS systems, perform the below steps

1. `vi ~/.bashrc`
2. add this line `alias test='/home/test.sh'`
3. `source ~/.bashrc` (optional step, unless you want your current session to have the updated bashrc, else a restart/logout/login should not require this step!)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand step nº3. I've got the next messages when I executed.


-ksh: .[5]: .[37]: shopt: not found [No such file or directory]
-ksh: .[5]: .[38]: hist: -a: unknown option
Usage: hist [-lnprs] [-e editor] [-N num] [first [last] ]
-ksh: .[5]: .[40]: shopt: not found [No such file or directory]
-ksh: .[5]: .[51]: shopt: not found [No such file or directory]

Comment: what shell are you using? also try again without bash in step 2 which would be `alias test='/home/test.sh'` Also make sure you have executable permission on the file `test.sh` which is `chmod +x test.sh`

Comment: Ok, now It works. I deleted the text "bash" and also I've wrote the path exactly where the test.sh was. I was specificaing the path with "ln" (softlink)

Comment: Also note you had to do Step 3 so that the bashrc takes into effect in the current logged in session but for future when you reboot/start/logout and login then the source won't be necessary! FYI

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your own commands and have them tab-complete without browsing to their directory you would begin by looking at your $PATH variable

`echo $PATH`

This should return a list of variables in your current path
*if you want to edit your path click [here](https://www.mediacollege.com/linux/red-hat/path-variable.html)*

I may suggest a common place location for your link in /usr/bin

Certain distributions will often include ~/bin in their $PATH, using this location may or may not explain why your tab-complete is completing the full and not just the command

`ln -s /home/test.sh /usr/bin/test`

Also, you may want to consider as a personal preference utilizing the /opt directory to keep things organised, for example

`ln -s /opt/scripts/test.sh /usr/bin/test`

Comment: Ok, thank you for you support. Well, my directory was on $PATH. I'll check your suggestions. Thanks.